# How to write on ExternalStorage of Emulator

Tags: android, android-file

I am trying to write folders (make folders) on mnt/sdcard/ but directory is not making on emulator external strorage.

Is there any way to create folders and files on Emulator's External Storage

Code:

```
File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+"myNewDir");
        success =file.mkdir();
```

if(!success)

//Not Created

esle

//Created

Comment: have you add file.createFile();

Comment: no, but i tried it now it also giving no such file and directory found: File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+"obb"+"/"+this.getPackageName());
         try {
    file.createNewFile();
   } catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
   }

Comment: Have you set permission in manifest   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: yes i set it in manifest